# Can't update Eclipse Indigo to Sequoyah  Can't install Sequoyah plugin

Tags: eclipse

When I select the following repository, I don't get any options.  Nothing shows up. All the indigo sites are fine but not Sequoyah.

Sequoyah Metadata Repository - http://download.eclipse.org/sequoyah/updates/2.0/

I'm on Indigo version of Eclipse.  I have installed the C/C++ CDT.

Comment: Sequoyah site might be down or moved. Ask their support.

Comment: Try unchecking "Group items by category" in the "install new software" Eclipse window.

Comment: +1 for unchecking "Group items by category" - works

Comment: +2 for Try unchecking "Group items by category"

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same error too. I did some lookup and found what might be a workaround.

Take the link
 Indigo - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo

In the "Mobile and Device Development" section you should see Sequoyah among the choices.

It's kind of strange we have to proceed this way but i worked for me.